# What topics should I study to understand this document?

Tags: reference-request, advice

**Background**
I'm trying to understand [a document I found online](http://www.math.uh.edu/~rohop/fall_03/Downloads/Skript/Chapter4a.pdf). The reason I'm reading it is because I need to translate the Nedelec element into code for my research.

**Problem**
My background is in Food Science, which is mostly biology/chemistry. I do have high interest in math, but my highest math education (classes + online self learning) is only ODE and Calculus 3. I tried reading the document, but I do not understand most of it.

In the following section, I list certain parts of the document I have difficulty with. While a direct answer is appreciated, if you could share with me **what topic/book I should study** so that I can have a deep understanding and appreciation for the concept involved, you will have my unending gratitude.

**Specific examples from the document**

- Equation (4.2) : I don't understand the ( , )<sub>0, Ω</sub> notation. Is this set theory?
- Equation (4.8) : From what I understand, the caret-like symbol (^) is sort of like a cross-product, but it really means a wedge product, which I don't know where to study about it. Is this exterior algebra?
- The proof section just slightly below (4.9) : Why would finding a solution to **z**<sub>h</sub> prove that **curl(q**<sub>h</sub>) belongs to the Lebesgue space? Also, the first part of the proof involves a combination of integration by parts and Stokes theorem, but how did he suddenly jump into that bloated integrand with lots of wedge products?

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: $(\cdot,\cdot)_{0,\Omega}$ is some inner product defined on the given vector space (to make it a Hilbert space), often we write $(\cdot,\cdot)$ as $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$. I don't completely understand the rest of the notation.

Comment: For whatever it might be worth, in my opinion the listed prerequisites for the course this handout is for -- Calculus, Linear Algebra, Numerical Analysis -- don't come anywhere near to giving someone the needed background for that handout, unless "calculus" means advanced calculus (preferably something like Loomis/Sternberg), "linear algebra" means Hoffman/Kunze or Halmos level, and "numerical analysis" means something that involves functional analysis stuff.

Comment: @Eff What would the '0' in (⋅,⋅)<sub>0,Ω</sub> mean?

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Should I read up those books that you mention then? I've seen them being mentioned around the stackexchange website.

Comment: I can't know *for sure*, unless if they define it explicitly in the text. Often within Finite Element we define a set of functions that have support in some domain $\Omega$ (that is, they are zero outside this domain), and that's what the $0$ sometimes symbolizes. For example, sometimes the following inner product is defined
$$\langle f,g\rangle = \int_\Omega \nabla f\cdot\nabla g.$$

Comment: Regarding your question about "those books", I'm not even sure you have the background for them (assuming you only have had ODE and Calculus 3), except maybe the linear algebra texts. If you really want to stick with this, the best thing I can think of right now is to get a copy of C. H. Edwards' **Advanced calculus of several variables** and Wendell H Fleming's **Functions of Several Variables**, and try to quickly work your way through both books (they're very similar, so doing both should help if you're mostly studying this by yourself). Maybe try skipping ahead to relevant parts, also.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'll try and check those out.